# How to stop CodeMirror from moving cursor on keyup?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to skip certain, uneditable (XML-)tags in my code, using CodeMirror. In order to do that, I have to 'stop' (preventDefault) the keyup event, do some logic and move the cursor. PreventDefault and codemirrorIgnore don't work or do not do what I need them to do. Do I have to catch the event outside CodeMirror? :(

Does not work:

`codeMirror.on('keyup', function (cm, ev) {
  ev.codemirrorIgnore = true;
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the below code you can handle the up arrow functionality

```
codeMirror.setOption("extraKeys", {"Up":function()
{
 console.log("Key Up pressed");
if(true) // logic to decide whether to move up or not
{
 return CodeMirror.PASS;
}
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you actually want is [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) with the `atomic` and `readOnly` options, rather than messing with key events (which won't really prevent the user from entering/editing the text).